# Timeout on Kinesis Port when creating Kinesis Stream on Localstack

Tags: docker-compose, amazon-kinesis, localstack

I'm trying to create a Kinesis stream using Localstack running on Docker.

My docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack:latest
    container_name: localstack_test_serialize
    ports:
      - '4563-4599:4563-4599'
      - '8055:8080'
    environment:
      - SERVICES=s3,kinesis:4569
      - DEBUG=1
      - DATA_DIR=/tmp/localstack/data
    volumes:
      - './.localstack:/tmp/localstack'
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
```

Running `docker-compose up -d` starts everything just fine, and I'm able to create an S3 bucket on the normal S3 port.

However, when I try to run 
`aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4569 kinesis create-stream --stream-name sample-application-stream --shard-count 1` 
to create a Kinesis stream, I end up getting a timeout message for port 4569.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong or why Localstack isn't letting me create this stream?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the port 4568.

The [LocalStack documentation](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) mark this port to use kinesis.